# The connection manager size is too big in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, business-intelligence

I just download VS2017 and it turns out the font size in connection manager is super big and so is components. is there anyway to fix this?[image: notice I have zoom in to almost 50% of its original size]

Comment: notice that I have zoom out the component to 50% percents of its original size

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your resolution settings to a slightly lower value (for example, if you are using remote desktop, change the remote desktop settings down from 'Full Screen').

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. It seems to me that Visual Studio 2017 is optimized for resolutions of 2880x1620 or higher. Everything looks fairly proportionate at this resolution. Though if increasing your resolution is not a valid solution, your best bet is to downgrade to an older version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue using Windows 10 and VS 2017 when my resolution was up to 3840 X 2160. Because the resolution is so high windows has a display setting to "Change the size of text Apps and other items" and the default is set to 300%.

In settings under Display when I changed this to a lower value the size of the items in VS's connection manager window display at a more reasonable size, the only drawback to that is that other items in other applications displayed smaller too.